# Best way to store JQuery variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xhtml

I just want to get some thoughts on storing variables for JQuery's use.

Example

Here JQuery would use the the value of the `video_id` hidden input, and then `voteup` the video by the `video_id`.

```
 <form class='voteup' action='' method='post'>
   <input type="hidden" name='video_id' value='<?php echo $video_id; ?>' />
   <input type='submit' value='Vote Up' />
 </form>
```

Note: This is just an example.

But what if I want a link to do the same thing. Where would I store the `video_id`?

Obviously, I could store the `video_id` in the `class` attribute, but I don't think that this is the best way, especially if I needed to send more than one variable.

Any ideas on this?

I must mention that I'm only looking for XHTML valid ways.

Comment: `$("a").data("video_id")` - see http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: @RobW You have so much reputation already that you don't need to post that as an actual answer? ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the jQuery [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method to attach arbitrary data to an element. In your case, if I've understood what you're trying to do correctly, you probably want to do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#yourLink").data("video_id", "<?php echo $video_id; ?>");
});
```

As you are looking for valid XHTML solutions, you can't use the HTML5 `data-*` attributes. If that was the case, you could add the attribute value directly on the element (as you've done with the `value` attribute in your example).

The `data` method does not require a corresponding `data-*` attribute to be present on the element, so this will still allow you to write valid XHTML.

Comment: This is quite true, but sometimes it's nice to be able to completely separate the markup from the behavioral code.  That's why including relevant adjunct properties in the markup itself is useful.

Comment: Agreed, but without the ability to use `data-*` attributes you're left with not much choice. As you mentioned, you could use `rel` but that's not great semantically. I guess it's up to the OP which they prefer.

Answer (score 2):

If you digg HTML5 you should go for the data attribute.

http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Answer (score 1):

In an HTML 5 page, you can use "data-" attributes for things like that:

```
<img src='http://placekitten.com/100/100' data-video-id='whatever'>
```

Then, from jQuery:

```
$('img').click(function() {
  var video = $(this).data('video-id'); // 'videoId' also works here
});
```

If you're (tragically) stuck with strict XHTML, well, you're stuck. For an `<a>` tag you could possibly use the "rel" attribute I guess. In general "class" is probably in fact the thing to do. The convention I've used for name-value pairs in the "class" is to separate them with a colon and then extract them via regex:

```
<sometag class='whatever videoId:video22 something'>
```

and then:

```
$('sometag').click(function() {
  var videoId = this.className.replace(/videoId:(\S*)/, '$1');
  // ...
});
```

Comment: @NathanAnderson yes but they don't conform to strict XHTML.  You can't use arbitrary attributes in XHTML if you want the code to validate, in other words.

Comment: I don't agree. There are plenty of ways to form a valid document without adding arbitrary attributes. I find HTML5 is too new and can break across platforms. As XHTML is valid XML, 99% platforms can understand it without having to guess at tags.

Comment: HTML 5 is explicitly designed to capture *actual* behavior of *actual* browsers. And XHTML actually *does not work* the way it's supposed to in Internet Explorer, and it never has.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use the `rel` attribute, and grab it in jQuery using the `.attr()` method.

```
var myVar = $('#link_id').attr('rel');
```

http://api.jquery.com/attr/